# Unable to distribute app using Developer ID distribution method

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm following [Apple's guide for notorizing an app for distribution](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/notarizing_macos_software_before_distribution), and one of the requirements is to use the Developer ID distribution method. However, it isn't listed as the guide explains. These are the only distribution methods I find:

[image]

I do have a valid developer ID and I'm signed into xCode with my apple developer account. I'm unable to notorize the app due to this absence. What could I be missing? I'm running xcode version 13.0

Comment: Can you verify that your archive is for a Mac app and not an iOS app? When distributing an iOS app, I get the same screen as you. When distributing a Mac app, I get the right screen.

Comment: Yes, notarised distribution is only for macOS apps.  iOS apps must be distributed through the App Store